# how to convert a node list to an edge list in igraph?

Tags: r, igraph, convex-hull

I have a empty graph and need to plot the graph based on the convex hull with inner verticies.

My attemp is:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(45)
n = 10

g <- graph.empty(n)
xy      <- cbind(runif(n), runif(n))
    
vp <- convex_hull(xy)$resverts + 1
#[1]  8 10  7  2  1

## convert node_list to edge_list

plot(g, layout=xy)
```

Expected result in right figure.

[image]

Question. How to convert a node list to an edge list in igraph??

Comment: Your code is not reproducible, there's no `M`. As for the main question, are you looking for `as_edgelist(g)`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas, I have rewrite the code. My graph is empty on the start, then i have found ids of vertex: 8,10,7,2,1 and need to convert to: 8,10,10,7,7,2,2,1,1,8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `add_edges` along with `embed`

```
g2 <- g %>%
  add_edges(c(t(embed(vp, 2)), vp[1], vp[length(vp)])) %>%
  as.undirected()
```

and `plot(g2, layout = xy)` in turn gives

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`convex_hull` does not output a node list in the same sense that an `igraph` object has a node list. In this case, `vp` is the sequence of indices so in order to create an edge list, you just need to have the from vertex be going to the next vertex in the sequence. This can be accomplished with `dplyr::lead` using the first vertex as the default to create a circuit.

```
data.frame(
  from = vp,
  to = dplyr::lead(vp, 1, default = vp[1])
)
#>   from to
#> 1    8 10
#> 2   10  7
#> 3    7  2
#> 4    2  1
#> 5    1  8
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
## create graph.
vids <- as.character(c(8, 10, 7, 2, 1))
g <- make_graph(c(), length(vids))
V(g)$name <- vids

## and connect the dots.
g2 <- g + path(c(vids, vids[1]))
g2
```