# How to use the convex_hull() function in the loop?

Tags: r, igraph, convex-hull

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74238114/how-to-convert-a-node-list-to-an-edge-list-in-igraph) I have used the convex_hull() function. We have a graph, where all nodes have zero degree and (x,y) coordinats. We need to create graph as sequence of convex hulls. We can stop the loop if only just one node has zero degree.

My attempt is:

```
library(igraph)
######################################################################
set.seed(5)
n=15
g  <- graph.empty(n)
xy <- cbind(runif(n), runif(n))
in_points <- V(g)[degree(g)==0]

repeat {
cp <- convex_hull(xy[in_points, ])$resverts+1

g <- as.undirected(add_edges(g, c(t(embed(cp, 2)), cp[1], cp[length(cp)])))

in_points <- V(g)[degree(g)==0]
if (length(in_points)=1) {break}
}

plot(g, vertex.size=10, layout=xy)
```

One can see in the repeate loop the node `3` used twice.

Expected result is:

[image]

**Question.** How are correctly use output of convex_hull() function for  sequential adding edges in the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iteratively use `chull` and `add_edges`. You just need to make sure that input to `add_edges` is of correct format and track which nodes are not already part of outer convex hull.

```
xy <- cbind(seq_len(n), xy)

while(nrow(xy) > 1){
  current_hull <- chull(xy[,2], xy[,3])
  current_hull <- c(current_hull, current_hull[[1]])
  g <- add_edges(g, as.vector(t(embed(xy[,1][current_hull], 2)[,2:1])))
  xy <- xy[-current_hull,,drop = FALSE]
}
```